# How to remove duplicate lines in a file based on two columns in python, without using pandas?

Tags: python, duplicates

I currently have a file which looks like this:

```
Fruit         Shop         Price
Apple         Shop A       $2.00
Apple         Shop A       $3.50
Apple         Shop B       $1.50
Apple         Shop B       $2.70
Apple         Shop B       $2.75
Apple         Shop C       $2.10
Orange        Shop A       $4.00
Orange        Shop A       $4.50
Orange        Shop C       $1.00
Orange        Shop C       $5.00
```

But would like to collapse based on "Fruit" and "Shop" columns so it looks more like this:

```
Fruit         Shop         Price
Apple         Shop A       $2.00
Apple         Shop B       $2.70
Apple         Shop C       $2.10
Orange        Shop A       $4.00
Orange        Shop C       $1.00
```

Just keeping the cheapest instance. I then want to count the number of shops for each fruit to make a table like this:

```
Apple         3
Orange        2
```

I've done this with a pandas dataframe which is simple enough but I was wondering what would be a way to write this in python without pandas? I have very large files and it is quite slow to do this in pandas and some of the file formats are not working very well with pandas.

I am new to stack overflow so I hope I am not asking a bad question...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like task for `itertools.groupby`, it can be done following way

```
import itertools
data = [['Apple', 'Shop A', 2.00], ['Apple', 'Shop A', 3.50], ['Apple', 'Shop B', 1.50], ['Apple', 'Shop B', 2.70], ['Apple', 'Shop B', 2.75], ['Apple', 'Shop C', 2.10], ['Orange', 'Shop A', 4.00], ['Orange', 'Shop A', 4.50], ['Orange', 'Shop C', 1.00], ['Orange', 'Shop C', 5.00]]
unique = []
for _,group in itertools.groupby(data,key=lambda x:x[0]+x[1]):
    unique.append(min(list(group),key=lambda y:y[-1]))
for i in unique:
    print(*i,sep='\t')
```

Output:

```
Apple   Shop A  2.0
Apple   Shop B  1.5
Apple   Shop C  2.1
Orange  Shop A  4.0
Orange  Shop C  1.0
```

For clarity I hardcoded `data`, note that it is `list` of `list`s and in each sublist last element is `float`, not `str`. In `itertools.groupby` I used contatenation of first two elements as `key`, thus for example two first records gets `AppleShopA` and go into one group. Then at each group I use `min` function with appropiate `key` so it would find element with lowest price.

`itertools` is "battery included" of Python, but if you are comfortable with SQL queries you might use another "battery included" namely `sqlite3` by creating SQL table from your data and then writing SQL query with GROUP BY.

Comment: Just another question, how would I alter this to take the first instance of the entry instead of the minimum value? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @epigeneticist: to get 1st instance replace `min(list(group),key=lambda y:y[-1])` with `list(group)[0]`

Comment: That's great, thanks! Would this also work when I have other columns as well in my data frame or list of lists? I'm trying this approach on my file which has 700 columns and I am trying to group by 2 columns as above and keep the minimum score but it isn't removing all the duplicates!

Comment: @epigeneticist: Note that before feeding data into `itertools.groupby` it needs to be sorted, so duplicates are neighbours, this is true for your example data so I assumed that is true for all your data